# Converting from Flask to Django

Tags: python, django, flask, response

What is Django's equivalent of the data type flask.wrappers.Response?

```
if request.method == "GET":
    data = open("print.txt","r")        
    response_r = app.response_class(
        response=data,
        status=200,
        mimetype='text/plain'
    )
```

As shown in the code above, response_r's datatype() is flask.wrappers.Response and I want to use this code in Django (not flask).

Answer (score 3):

This is the Django equivalent:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = open("print.txt", "r")   
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="text/plain")
```